# Will a local install of TFS show up as an available instance for other users?

Tags: tfs

I was thinking about installing TFS on my development Window 7 computer so I can have a sandbox to test things in TFS on a project that I know I have control over.

Right now I see the other TFS instances that we have stood (prod10\deve10\tfs08)  I don't know if I see those b/c of some setup\config on part of the systems\admin's or b/c they are on a server os, or for some other reason.

My question is, if I do install TFS, will other people see that instance in there available TFS servers when attempting to connect or change connections in Visual Studio?  If so it there a way to prevent that, essentially making the instance private (which I guess is kind of an odd request since tfs it is about collaboration).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default your local instance of TFS won't appear on your colleagues available servers. If they attempt to connect to your TFS instance and you haven't granted them permissions to the projects or collections then effectively your local instance will remain private.